Fail to connect MatrixOne (from GitHub)
When using the github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql driver to connect to matrixone, connecting with the default user root works fine, but attempting to connect using the account:username:role mode fails, resulting in the error:
select failed: err[Error 20101 (HY000): internal error: there is no user.

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    _, err := sql.Open("mysql","account:admin:role:xxx@tcp(192.168.110.210:6001)/ssb")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("connect failed: err[%v]", err)
        return
    }
}


Connection fails when including the tenant name because the username contains a colon (:), and in Go language when connecting to the MatrixOne database, the username and password are separated by a colon.
Therefore, when the username includes a colon, it causes the tenant name before the colon to be interpreted as the system tenant 'sys' username, resulting in a connection failure. To avoid this issue, you can use url.QueryEscape to encode the username and then concatenate the string.
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    username := "account:admin:role"
    encodeUsername := url.QueryEscape(username)
    _, err := sql.Open("mysql", encodeUsername+":xxx@tcp(192.168.110.210:6001)/ssb")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("connect failed: err[%v]", err)
        return
    }
}

